# how to disable free shipping if an attribute is true

Tags: attributes, onepage-checkout, if

I have created an if statement which I have on my shipping page. Where if the attribute "direct delivery" is true then it will display an error message and not show free delivery. I have put the If statement below.

```
<?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach ($cartItems as $item)
        {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                   if($product->getData('direct_delivery_product')==1){?>

             <div class="direct_message">
             <?php echo 'You have direct delivery products in your shopping cart. This means it may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days to deliver.';?></div>

                <?php unset($_shippingRateGroups["freeshipping"]);
                 break;
             }

                }

?>
```

However on my basket page where it displays the total it still says the delivery is free. I tried adding my IF statement to the template file where it displays the shipping but that didnt work. Could anyone tell me how i can get it display the standard shipping fee instead of free shipping. If the attribute is true. This is my the template file which shows the delivery on the basket page.

```
<?php if ($this->displayBoth()):?>
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getExcludeTaxLabel() ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingExcludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getIncludeTaxLabel() ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingIncludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>


<?php elseif($this->displayIncludeTax()) : ?>
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingIncludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php else:?>


<tr>

    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()) ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingExcludeTax()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the free shipping carrier model `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` and add this method inside your new class

```
public function proccessAdditionalValidation(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $items = $request->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) { 
        if ($items->getProduct()->getData('direct_delivery_product')) {
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this should disable the free shipping method when a product with `direct_delivery_product` set to yes is in your cart.